# react native - On button press load the whole screen with parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile, react-native

I am trying to load my parent component from child component on button press. But it's not rendering the parent components from `btnPress` method. I am not getting any error.

onButtonPress

```
<Button onPress={() => btnPress(parent_id, id)}>
                <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
</Button>
```

btnPress Function

```
function btnPress(parent_id, id) {
       const App = () => (
         //I have tried this way but this didn't work. No any error, i can see log on console
         <Container> 
           <Headerc headerText={'Fitness sdaf'} />
           <ExerciseList pId={parent_id} mId={id} />
         </Container>
       );  
         console.log(id);  
        AppRegistry.registerComponent('weightTraining', () => App);
    }
```

full code(child component)

```
import React from 'react'; 
import { Right, Body, Thumbnail, Container, ListItem, Text, Icon } from 'native-base';
import { AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';
import Headerc from './headerc';
import ExerciseList from './exerciseList';

import Button from './Button';


const ExerciseDetail = ({ exercise }) => {
  const { menu_name, menu_icon, parent_id, id } = exercise;

function NumberDescriber() {
      let description;
      if (menu_icon === 'noimg.jpg') {
        description = `http://www.xxxxxx.com/uploads/icons/${menu_icon}`;
      } else if (menu_icon === 'noimg.jpg') {
        description = menu_icon;
      } else {
        description = `http://www.xxxxx.com/uploads/icons/${menu_icon}`;
      }
  return description;
}

function btnPress(parent_id, id) {
   const App = () => (
     <Container>
       <Headerc headerText={'Fitness sdaf'} />
       <ExerciseList pId={parent_id} mId={id} />
     </Container>
   );

     console.log('-------------------------------');
       console.log(id); 
       console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
    AppRegistry.registerComponent('weightTraining', () => App);
}

return (
  <ListItem>
    <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: NumberDescriber() }} />
    <Body>
      <Text>{menu_name}</Text>
      <Text note> {menu_name} exercise lists</Text>
    </Body>
    <Right>
    <Button onPress={() => btnPress(parent_id, id)}>
        <Icon name="arrow-forward" />
    </Button>
    </Right>
  </ListItem>

  );
 }; 

export default ExerciseDetail;
```

Please do let me know, if you need more information.

Comment: What's the reason behind having AppRegistry there? You're also probably in need of a navigation library by the sounds of it

Comment: @linasmnew I kept it by thinking it will work .

Comment: You want to navigate to parent component from this component?

Comment: @linasmnew Yes!

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest doing that way, it look totally anti-pattern and not.
better try with navigation or create a pattern like this

inside your index.js or index.android.js or index.ios.js

```
import App from './App'    //your app level file
AppRegistry.registerComponent('weightTraining', () => App);
```

now in your app js file

```
export default App class extends React.Component{
 constructor(props){
   super(props);
   this.state ={
    component1:false,
    component2:true,  
  }
 }

btnPressed =()=>{
//handle state update logic here
}
render(){
  if(this.state.component1) return <Component1/>
  return <Component2/>
}
}
```

**** not the best solution available, play around and you will get best

Comment: how to define  `component1,
    component2` globally?

Comment: these 2 can be just functional component or class component (same way as I defined App class

Answer (score 0):

To navigate from this component to your parent component unless you want to implement your own navigation which isn't recommended, you should look into one that's already built and adopted by many in the react-native ecosystem.

Some of the biggest ones:

- [React Native Navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-navigation)
- [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org)
- [React Native Router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-router-flux)

I personally highly recommend option number 1, since it seems to be the most production tested and production ready implementation out there